# How to generate checksum from hex byte using python

Tags: python, byte, hex, checksum, crc

I am creating a hex file using python and at the end I need to add a checksum that consists of sum of all hex values so that checksum = Byte 0x000000 + Byte 0x000001 + … + Byte 0x27DAFF (not including this 4 bytes). This checksum shall then be written to buffer at position 0x27DB00-0x27DB03 as unsigned long.

Any good ideas for how to get this done fast, I am running python2.7.

As info of what I am up to I start with creating a buffer using `ctypes`, then write lots and lots of hex stuff to buffer, then create a `cStringIO` from buffer and write this string object to a `file_obj` which happen to be a django http response (i.e. returns the hex file as downloadable file) so any smart things involving the buffer would be appreciated

Comment: By a "hex file", do you just mean a binary file?

Comment: Did you try `sum()` on a `bytearray`?

Comment: ...using
b = ctypes.create_string_buffer

Answer (score 4):

the following two solutions worked:

```
checksum = sum(map(ord, b))
```

or:

```
checksum = sum(bytearray(b))
```